# Fragment and Fragment communication

Tags: android, fragment, communication, pause

Hi there my question is this. I hava a fragment inside a View Pager that has a button that when is tabbed a bottom sheet is opened with another fragment inside. The bottom sheet has a list of objects and when the user has selected one I want to pass that object to the first fragment that I mentioned earlier, the problem is that that fragment is paused. 
How can I send data from one fragment to another that is paused?

Comment: Check fragment lifecycle.

Comment: An what have tired so far?

Comment: @Andrea Fragment will paused if your activity is in on-pause state.

You can use interface for communication between fragment

Comment: use bundle to transfer data between fragments

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to pass data between fragments. Few are:

1. You can use getter/setter of participating fragments class
2. You can share data among fragment using their parent activity
3. You can use interface for updating/passing data between fragments or activity
4. You can use Observer Design Pattern to share/pass data between fragments or activities
5. You can also use Bundle to pass data

It depends on you to choose best approach that suits your need.

Comment: Does this aproach works even if the Fragment that I want to pass the information is in onPause()? Because I don´t wan´t to create that Fragment again

Comment: @andrea, yes, choose best approach that suits you.

Comment: I´ve tried the Bundle option but don´t work since the Fragment that I want to pass the info is already created and getArguments() won´t do anything inside onResume()

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        System.out.print(position + "to" + tab_position);


        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("message", "getdata");
                bundle.putStringArrayList("name", running_veicle);
                bundle.putStringArrayList("loc", running_loc);
                bundle.putStringArrayList("running_device_id", running_device_id);
                fragment = new Vehicle_Status_fragment_running_info();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);


                break;
            case 1:

                Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
                bundle1.putString("message", "getdata");
                bundle1.putStringArrayList("name", idle_name);
                bundle1.putStringArrayList("loc", idle_loc);
                bundle1.putStringArrayList("idle_device_id", idle_device_id);
                fragment = new Vehicle_Status_fragment_Idle_info();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle1);

                break;
            case 2:

                Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
                bundle2.putString("message", "getdata");
                bundle2.putStringArrayList("name", stop_name);
                bundle2.putStringArrayList("loc", stop_loc);
                bundle2.putStringArrayList("stop_device_id", stop_device_id);
                fragment = new Vehicle_Status_fragment_Stop_info();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle2);
                break;

            case 3:
                Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
                bundle3.putString("message", "getdata");
                bundle3.putStringArrayList("name", Innactive_name);
                bundle3.putStringArrayList("loc", Innactive_loc);
                bundle3.putStringArrayList("innactive_device_id", Innactive_device_id);
                fragment = new Vehicle_Status_fragment_Inactive_info();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle3);
                break;

        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 4 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.tab_Running).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.tab_Idle).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.tab_Stop).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.tab_Innactive).toUpperCase(l);

        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

*get data*

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_veicle_status_list, container, false);
    listobj = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    String myValue = this.getArguments().getString("message");
```

Comment: Does this aproach works even if the Fragment that I want to pass the information is in onPause()? Because I don´t wan´t to create that Fragment again